# Cant select an entity by id in .net Odata Implementation

Tags: .net, api, rest, asp.net-mvc-4, odata

```
// GET api/Product/5
    public Product GET([FromODataUri]int id)
    {
        Product product = db.Products.Find(id);
        if (product == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
        }
        return product;
    }
```

**this above of getting entity with ID is never called with my url :**

```
http://localhost:53208/odata/Product(1)
```

even with default settings in odata route this is not called.

first i was trying with this odata route settings:

```
 config.Routes.MapODataRoute("ODataRoute", "odata", GetEdmModel());
```

remember my simple Get with queries is working fine. but this is the only thing which is working, and PUT method is working. other all are not working. this is view of controller. **I have tried for about a day.. please help.**

```
public class ProductController : ODataController
{
    private OfferAssistantDbContext db = new OfferAssistantDbContext();

    // GET api/Product
    public IQueryable<Product> GET()
    {

        return db.Products.AsQueryable<Product>();
    }

    // GET api/Product/5
    public Product GET([FromODataUri]int id)
    {
        Product product = db.Products.Find(id);
        if (product == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
        }

        return product;
    }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Web API OData is particular with parameter names. The parameter name should be `key` instead of `id` i.e.

```
public Product GET([FromODataUri]int key)
{
}
```

Comment: The problem arose due to my change of API controller to ODataController and I did know about key and id difference.

Comment: Thanks buddy ! I wasted lot of time to figure this out !

Comment: `public IHttpActionResult Patch([FromODataUri(Name = "key")] int whateverYouWantId)`

Comment: is there anyway to ask for array of keys?